# Saga watcher not receiving or processing dispatched action

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-saga

I have a watcher saga that is constantly listening for actions of a certain type. This is started up from the saga.run(). When it receives an action of a certain type, it should then call into another saga which performs async actions. However a breakpoint inside the second saga is never getting called.

So either the originating code is not dispatching the action correctly, or the watcher saga is configured wrong.

Watcher saga code

```
import { all, fork, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import {fetchItems} from './itemsSaga';

function* watchLoadItemsRequest() {
  while(true) {
    yield takeLatest('FETCH_ITEMS_REQUEST', fetchItems);
  }
}    

export default function* root() {
  yield all ([
    fork(watchLoadItemsRequest)
  ])
}
```

My itemsSaga (that isn't being called)

```
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import fetchItemsCompleted from '../actions/fetchItemsCompleted';
import httpCallCompleted from '../actions/httpCallCompleted';
import httpCallStarted from '../actions/httpCallStarted';
import itemAPI from '../api/itemAPI';
import ItemsEntity from '../api/itemEntity';

// worker Saga: will be fired on FETCH_ITEMS_REQUEST actions
export function* fetchItems(action:any) {
  let items : ItemEntity[];

  yield put(httpCallStarted());
  trades = yield call(itemAPI.getAllItemsAsync)
  trades = [new ItemEntity(), new ItemEntity()]
  yield put(fetchItemsCompleted(items))
  yield put(httpCallCompleted());
}
```

My store creation code

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';

import reducers  from '../reducers';
import watchersSaga from '../sagas/watchersSaga';

export default function getStore() {
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

    const store = createStore(
      reducers, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
    );

    sagaMiddleware.run(watchersSaga);

    return store;
  }
```

And lastly the control which should send the FETCH_ITEMS_REQUEST action

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect, Dispatch } from 'react-redux';
import ItemEntity from './api/itemEntity';
import './App.css';
import IStoreState from './interfaces/IStoreState';

interface IContentProps {
  groupingType : string,
  items: ItemEntity[],
  loadItems : () => void
}

class MyContent extends React.Component<IContentProps,{}> {

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
  }

  public componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadItems();
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <div className="Center-content">
        <div className="Center-content White">
        <br/><br/>Grouped by {this.props.groupingType}<br/><br/>{this.props.items.length} items loaded
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }


}

function mapStateToProps(state: IStoreState) {
  return {
    groupingType: state.navigation.groupingType,
    trades: state.item.items
  };
}    

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
  return {
    loadItems: () => dispatch({type:'FETCH_ITEMS_REQUEST'})
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PnlContent);
```

Why isn't this working? Is there a way I can tell whether or not the FETCH_ITEMS_REQUEST is actually being generated and sent to redux or not? That way at least I could narrow down where the problem is occurring.

UPDATE: I've tweaked one of my reducers to listen to the FETCH_ITEMS_REQUEST and it picks up the event, so my control is dispatching the action fine. It just seems the WatcherSaga is not triggering the ItemsSaga fetchItems() method when it receives a FETCH_ITEMS_REQUEST action so I think the problem is in my watchersSaga

SECOND UPDATE:

More and more I think the problem lies with the lines

```
while(true) {
    yield takeLatest('FETCH_ITEMS_REQUEST', fetchItems);
  }
```

This doesn't seem to be responding to a received FETCH_ITEMS_REQUEST message and calling fetchItems

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone with a similar problem I ended up solving it by changing my watchers Saga to the following

```
function* watchLoadTradesRequest() {
    yield takeEvery('FETCH_TRADES_REQUEST', fetchTrades);
}

// Register all your watchers
export default function* watchersRootSaga() {
  yield all ([
    watchLoadTradesRequest()
  ])
}
```