# Saga watcher not calling saga worker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I read many other questions on the same problem, primarily this one: [Saga watcher not receiving or processing dispatched action](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50647711/12604905)

I changed my watchers saga and created a root saga as specified in the answer, but the watcher saga still doesn't call the worker saga.

My control dispatches the action fine, and both my root and watcher sagas get called.

Below is my code. My action gets dispatched through a form submission. In case that makes a significant difference, I included my control.

**Saga**

```js
import { takeEvery, put, all } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import * as mutations from './mutations';

// worker
function* createItem(action) {
  alert("ok");
}

// watcher
function* watchSubmitItem() {
  yield takeEvery(mutations.SUBMIT_ITEM, createItem);
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all ([
    watchSubmitItem()
  ]);
}
```

**Store**

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
import  rootSaga  from './sagas.mock';
import * as mutations from './mutations';

export const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    /*stuff that doesn't matter*/
  }),

  applyMiddleware(createLogger(), sagaMiddleware)
)

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)
```

**Control**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as mutations from '../store/mutations';

export const Main = ({
  submit_item,
})  => (
  <div>
    <div>
      <form onSubmit = {(e) => submit_item(e)}>
        <div>
        <div>
          <label>Thing 1</label>
          <select id = "thing1">
            <option value="op1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="op2">Option 2</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>Thing 2</label>
          <textarea id = "thing2" name = "thing2"/>
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>Thing 3</label>
          <input id = "thing3"/>
        </div>

        <div>
          <input type = "submit" value = "Submit"/>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
);

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    submit_item(e) {
        let thing1 = e.target[0].value;
        let thing2 = e.target[1].value;
        let thing3 = e.target[2].value;
        
        dispatch(mutations.submit_item(thing1, thing2, thing3));
    }
  }
}

export const ConnectedMain = connect(mapDispatchToProps) (Main);
```

**Mutations**

```js
export const SUBMIT_ITEM = 'SUBMIT_ITEM';

export const submit_item = (thing1, thing2, thing3) => ({
  type:SUBMIT_ITEM,
  thing1, thing2, thing3
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the way you call the `connect` function from react-redux. The first param is to map state not actions. If you don't have any, then you can use `null`.

```
export const ConnectedMain = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);
```

Also you need to call `stopPropagation` in the submit event, otherwise your page will refresh.

Finally you have extra `div` in the form, but I assume that is just a typo when moving code to stackoverflow.

Comment: Fixed--the problem was one of thing1, thing2, thing3 was named "type", which overwrote the action type from SUBMIT_ITEM to something else. While moving code to StackOverflow, I deleted and renamed parts I thought were irrelevant. Next time I ask a question on StackOverflow, I won't heavily edit my source code, lesson learned. I was looking to prevent page refresh though, and stopPropagation did the trick. Thank you.